# How to even out/scale this material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, pbr

I have this PBR set up and working, but I'm getting different results on different objects. I have UV unwrapped the objects (using smart unwrap). The texture itself is working. I have applied rotation and scale.

Per another thread, I added a UV Map node fed through a mapping node in order to scale, but it is not working. I am wondering if the color node and the mapping nodes need to be mixed somehow?

I tried just scaling the UVs in the UV Editor window, but it seemed to have no effect at all.

I also realize that the UV map has a specific UV group specified, so I am not sure how I can apply a material like this to multiple objects (perhaps name the UVs all the same?)

You can see on the cab how pronounced the material is, but on other objects it looks very flat and smaller.

You can look at the blend file here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4n7aqyfuik4oy6t/cab.blend?dl=0

[image]

UPDATED NODE SETUP

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify the Uv channel if there is only one per object, so leave that empty. Also remember to connect your mapping node to the vector input of each of your texture nodes.

Comment: Do I need to have a mapping node for each texture, or can I plug the same mapping node into all of them? (Or maybe it has to be that way).

Comment: although your textures aren't packed in the .blend file, it looks like they are properties of the same texture so yes you can use a single mapping node. However the scaling will appear different on each object shared by the material depending on their UV size, I generally scale the UVs per object to get a consistent texture size. Btw in your case I don't think you'll be needing to use the displacement socket in the material ouput.

Comment: I've packed the blend file with the materials here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ts9i0lesdl44kf/packed.blend?dl=0 

I connected them all and now it just all looks flat, so I must have done something wrong. Why would I not need displacement?

Comment: to clarify, you do still need the uv node to tell it what kind of mapping is being used, leaving the input (UV channel) blank will select the first UV channel of each object so it will work well with all objects. You can also use the Uv socket from the texture co-ordinate node instead. Since your using the Principled bsdf which has a normal socket, the displacement is only useful for vertex displacement with approximation (adaptive subsurf). It can be a very heavy way to add detail as you'll need a polygon almost every pixel and is generally only used for in extreme closeups or terrain.

Comment: Ok, I think I finally understand. I added my updated node setup to the post above. Is that correct? It does seem like adjusting the scale is finally doing something now.

Comment: yes that looks good!